# What is the proper way to improve an answer?

Tags: discussion, questions, edits

Recently, I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76160437/8283848) but didn't receive much attention. In the meantime, I researched and obtained a [*"custom"* working solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76161815/8283848) for my use case. After a few days, another person added a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76185116/8283848) that was backed by the official framework.

I'd love to improve this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76185116/8283848) in a way that includes a better example with simple JSON and nested JSON so that others can benefit from it.

I think I have two options to improve the post -

- Suggest an edit to the existing answer with example and all (this may get rejected)
- Update my answer (not sure is this will be considered as a copy & paste)

So, what is the best practice(s) to deal with such a situation?

Comment: It's fine to improve upon someone else's answer using an answer of your own if you properly give them credit for it. https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing

Comment: also... it seems you edited your question to specify that you needed it to handle *nested* json, which wasn't there before and in a sense invalidates the answer you received, since it didn't take into account nested json. That's generally frowned upon, as the user did provide a correct answer to the question that was originally asked and the edit effectively turned a correct answer into an incorrect (or, at minimum, lacking) one. I'd probably reverse that edit, and then just include the additional info in your answer addressing nested json.

Comment: That makes sense (btw, I reversed the edit). What about creating another post (Q&A) with a proper-rephrased question and answer with better examples and use-cases?

Comment: You can't "suggest an edit" - not really sure what that option means (unless you writing FAQ proposal... which you seem not to... on other hand it is not "specific-answer" either... confusing - consider [edit]).

Comment: Option 3: post a comment under the answer? That is what comments are for - discussing the content and then notably with the intent to see it improved. If anything, you may come to the conclusion you should do nothing.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: For users without enough rep to earn the "[edit posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit)" privilege, clicking the "Edit" button allows them to suggest edits, which then cause those suggested edits to appear in the [Suggested edits](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits) review queue. (If that review queue is full, new edits can't be suggested.)

Comment: @V2Blast if you check OP's rep (79K) they are way past that point :) There are plenty of request to allow high-rep user to "suggest" edits but all are ignored so far... The only option for us, 2K+ users, is to edit and rollback, which is quite awkward.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Ah, good point.

Answer (score 2):

[You are allowed to answer your own questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

> Stack Exchange has always explicitly encouraged users to answer their own questions.

If there is an answer that may be generic, but will be helpful to others who stumble upon the question, don't edit it to include your custom solution. Especially if the custom problem was not explicitly stated in the original question. Obvious but don't make an answer worse by editing it.

Answering your own questions documenting what *you* did and what worked for you is suggested as it allows others (or yourself) to find it in the future and document the knowledge for the community.

Other potential options depending on the specific situation include commenting or editing the answer to include some "no-go" attempts.